# ios - Subclassing an UIView inside another UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 UIViews both with a bit off code in them.

I can subclass one to a UIViewController like this `self.view addSubView:_msgView];` 
_msgView being a UIView.

Now _msgView is a Plain UIView that has a 0.7 Alpha to lay over the UIViewController.

now I have another UIView called menuButtons and I want to put that on top of the _msgView.

I was thinking I could use `[_msgView addSubView:_menuButton];` but that does not work and gives a warning

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'MenuButtons *__strong' to parameter of type 'UIView *'

**How do I put a UIView on top of another UIView?**

//EDITS:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SlideMessageView.h"
#import "definitions.h"


@interface MenuButtons : UIView
{
UIButton *onBack;
UIButton *onForward;
UIButton *onRefresh;
UIButton *onHome;
UIButton *onSafari;
UIButton *onChrome;
UIButton *onPocketReader;
UIButton *onSavePDF;
UIButton *onPrint;
UIButton *onShare;

SlideMessageView *msgView;

BOOL viewVisible;
}
```

The UIButtons have their @properties set below that.

Comment: what is the type of _menuButto? Note that what you are doing (adding subviews to a view) isn't subclassing at all, you are just manipulating an ordered collection of objects.

Comment: oh sorry:-) I thought it was...both _msgView and _menuButton are UIView

Comment: There must be something wrong in the declaration of your MenuButtons class as the [_msgView addSubView:_menuButton]; will work if both _msgView or _menuButton are UIView*. The error says that _menuButton is of type MenuButtons*, how is MenuButtons declared? Are you sure it inherits from UIView?

Comment: Can you post the `interface` definition for `MenuButtons`?

Comment: I have added the code - hope it helps:-)

Comment: Its seems _msgView is one of the fields of _menuButton  you are trying to add _menuButton as a subView of _msgView

Comment: @Neo yeah the reason that is, because the buttons created in _menuButton are added as a subView to _msgView

Comment: why dont you create _msgView object in your main view controller instead of having it as the field of _menuButton?

Comment: well I had it all in the one ViewController and it worked, but the file was over 1000 lines and I found I am repeating a few things and wanted to break the code up a bit - so that is why I am trying to take this route. it's a learning progress:-)

Comment: its just two lines of code. import #import "SlideMessageView.h" and define SlideMessageView *msgView; in your viewcontroller.h then u dont have to do this in _menuButton. aint it?

Comment: yeah, its getting a little messy with the trial n error - will clean it up a bit,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do 1 thing.. if u are generating both the views through code then add both views in self.view itself and set their frames separately.

i.e if 1st view is at top set the frame msgview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,100);
ans for second view someview.frame = CGRectMake(0,100,320,200);